# Django cross table model structure

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a *System* model, and an *Interface* model. An Interface is the combination between two systems. Before, this interface was represented as an Excel sheet (cross table). Now I'd like to store it in a database.

I tried creation an Interface model, with two foreign keys to System. This doesn't work because :

- It creates two different reverse relationships on the target model
- It doesn't avoid having duplicates (first and second rel swapped)

I used this code :

```
class SystemInterface(Interface):
    assigned_to = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    first_system = models.ForeignKey(System)
    second_system = models.ForeignKey(System)
```

Isn't there a better way to do this ?

I'd need to have symmetrical relations : it should'nt matter is a System is the "first" or "second" in an Interface.

Comment: Does the hierarchy of which is the first and which is the second system matter to you? Or is the relationship to the two systems that is important?

Comment: No it doesn't matter. I want the relationship to be symetrical. first=a;second=b should be equivalent to first=b;second=a

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "It creates two different reverse relationships on the target model"?

Comment: @stellarchariot : I am forced to set different related_names for each ForeignKey, if I don't the models won't be valid. And so I cannot efficiently retrieve the list of Systems associated to another System.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best simpliest to represent those models would be like this:

```
class System(models.Model):
    pass

class Interface(models.Model):
    assigned_to = models.ManyToManyField(to=User)
    system = models.ForeignKey(System)

    @property
    def systems(self):
        Interface.objects.get(system=self.system).interfacedsystem_set.all()         

class InterfacedSystem(models.Model):
    interface = models.ForeignKey(Interface)
    system = models.ForeignKey(System)
```

The add/remove of interfaced system is obviously left as an exercise to the reader, put should be fairly easy.

Comment: This is very interesting answer, I'm going to look at it more precisely, and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Looks okay till now :) Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use a many to many relationship [with extra fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships), but it can't be [symetrical](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

The table used for a many to many relation contain a row per relation between 2 models. The table used for a many to many relation from System to self, has one row per relation between two Systems. This is consistent with the fact that your model fits the structure of a model used for  [ManyToManyField.through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

Using an intermediary model allows to add fields like assigned_to to the many to many table.

It might be tricky to understand, but it should prevent the creation of SystemInterface(left_system=system_**a**, right_system=system_**b**). Note that I changed "first" by "left" and "second" by "right" for the purpose of representing a many to many relation row/instance, which has a "left" side and a "right" side.

Because they can't be symetrical, this won't solve the problem of having one SystemInterface(left_system=system_**a**, right_system=system_**b**) and one with SystemInterface(left_system=system_**b**, right_system=system_**a**). You should prevent that from happening in the [clean() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#django.db.models.Model.clean) of the SystemInterface - or any model used to represent the many to many table with a ManyToManyField.through model.

Comment: Sorry I cannot see how can that help me. An Interface is only between two systems, not more.

Comment: Thank you for your edit, I understood. But how is that better than the initial approach ? It does not allow me to have a single reverse relation, does it ?

Comment: It can't be symetrical, so you can't have a single reverse relation, as far as I know. I don't know if it's really going to be better, but you were asking for other ways to do it and that's one, worth trying.

Answer (score 2):

Since django doesn't support  symmetrical many-to-many relationships with extra data, you probably need to enforce this yourself.

If you have a convenient immutable value in the system (e.g. system id), you can create a predictable algorithm for which system will be stored in which entry in your table.  If the systems are always persistent by the time you create the Interface object, you can use the primary key.

Then, write a function to create the interface.  For example:

```
class System(models.Model):
def addInterface(self, other_system, user):
    system_interface = SystemInterface()
    system_interface.assigned_to = user
    if other_system.id < self.id:
        system_interface.first_system = other_system
        system_interface.second_system = self
    else:
        system_interface.first_system = self
        system_interface.second_system = other_system
    system_interface.save()
    return system_interface
```

Using this design, you can do the usual validation, duplication detection, etc. on the SystemInterface object.  The main point is that you enforce the constraint in your code rather than in the data model.

Does this make sense?

Comment: It does, this is anyway what I would have done if I didn't find anything else. However, wouldn't it be better having this code in the SystemInterface manager ? Because using your way, I won't be able to efficiently use the admin interface.